# How to get instance of MapView in ArcGIS and use between two useEffect hooks in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, instance, arcgis

```
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";

useEffect(() => {
  const map = new Map({
    basemap: "arcgis-topographic", // Basemap layer service
  });

  const view = new MapView({
    map: map,
    center: [longitude, latitude], // Longitude, latitude
    zoom: 11, // Zoom level
    container: container.current, // Div element
    popups: false, // Popups
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  //I need to use that MapView here
}, []);
```

I've save the view variable to the state/ref. But didnt work. How to access the instance of MapView as global variable

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Dostonbek .

Comment: @DSDmark I am using Arcgis map for my projet. When I place all the code, belongs to ArcGis, inside one UseEffect, dependencies change such as lat, long, the whole Map will be re-created. That's not what I want. I want to get instance of that MapView and use it's click event inside another useEffect, so It doesnt re-create.

Comment: Add these details in your question @Dostonbek. And About your question, You could declare the `view` variable globally. Which will make `MapView` instance available to multiple `useEffect` hooks.

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @Dostonbek,

As I explain in the above comment. You could declare the view variable globally. Either, you could use `ref` hook To make the `MapView` instance available to both `useEffect` hooks. Also, you can use   `useState` hook as wall.

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";

const mapViewRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  const map = new Map({
    basemap: "arcgis-topographic", // Basemap layer service
  });

  mapViewRef.current = new MapView({
    map: map,
    center: [longitude, latitude], // Longitude, latitude
    zoom: 11, // Zoom level
    container: container.current, // Div element
    popups: false, // Popups
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const mapView = mapViewRef.current;
  // Use the mapView instance here
}, []);
```

Comment: I've done like this. But It didnt work. It is working inside only the first useEffect

Comment: I've got the instance. But The functionalities are not working like mapView.when(callback), mapView.on('click', callback)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by utilizing react useState. If you set the state in the first useEffect you will be able to access all the functions you want. To ensure that the second useEffect is able to access the view add *view* to the dependency array of the second useEffect and make sure that the state is already set.

```
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";

const [view, setView] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  const map = new Map({
    basemap: "arcgis-topographic", // Basemap layer service
  });

  const view = new MapView({
    map: map,
    center: [longitude, latitude], // Longitude, latitude
    zoom: 11, // Zoom level
    container: container.current, // Div element
    popups: false, // Popups
  });
  setView(view)
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if(view){
    // now you are able to use the view here
  }
}, [view]);
```